# Integrate improper integral

Tags: calculus

Just don't know where to start from.
Looks like this integral converges.

$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}}dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Let $x=\tan(\theta)$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
I&=-2\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos(\theta))\,d\theta\\\\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(\theta))\\\\
&=\pi\log(2)
\end{align}$$

---

> **IN CASE YOU HAVE NOT SEE THIS DERIVATION:**

To see why $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta=-\pi\log(2)$, simply note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(\theta))\,d\theta&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}(\log(\sin(\theta))+\log(\cos(\theta)))\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac12\sin(2\theta)\right)\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin(2\theta)\right)\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac14\int_0^{\pi}\log\left(\sin(\theta)\right)\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin(\theta)\right)\,d\theta\\\\
\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin(\theta)\right)\,d\theta&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)\\\\
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\sin(\theta)\right)\,d\theta&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

A different approach: integrate "a la Feynman". Let
$$
F(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+t^2\,x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx.
$$
Then, differentiating inside the integral,
\begin{align*}
F'(t)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\,t\,x^2}{(1+t^2\,x^2)(1+x^2)}\,dx\\
&=\frac{2\,t}{1-t^2}\int_0^\infty\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+t^2\,x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\Bigr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{2\,t}{1-t^2}\Bigl(\frac1t\arctan(t\,x)-\arctan x\Bigl)\Bigr|_0^\infty\\
&=\frac{2\,t}{1-t^2}\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2\,t}-\frac\pi2\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{1+t}.
\end{align*}
Integrating
$$
F(t)=\pi\log(1+t)+C.
$$
Since $\lim_{t\to0^+}F(t)=F(0)=0$, $C=0$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+t^2\,x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\pi\log(1+t).
$$
Of course, differentiating under the integral sign and taking the limit as $t\to0^+$ must be justified.

Comment: Julian, his name was spelled "Feynman," not "Feynmann." ;-))

Comment: Please disregard that last comment. ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Changing variable $x\to\tan x$, one has
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\sec^2x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2+\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\sec x)dx=\pi\ln2.$$
Here
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\ln(\sec x)dx=\frac\pi2\ln2. $$

Comment: How is this different from mine? ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV, no big difference.

Comment: Great minds and all ... Although mine is far from great.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x & =
-2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta =
\left.-2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{z + 1/z \over 2}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}\,
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.-2\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + z^{2} \over 2z}\,{\dd z \over z}\,
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[1cm] & \stackrel{\mrm{\epsilon}\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}
2\,\Im\int_{1}^{\epsilon}\bracks{%
\ln\pars{1 - y^{2} \over 2y} - {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}\,{\dd y \over y}
\\ & +
2\,\Im\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\bracks{%
-\ln\pars{2} - \ln\pars{\epsilon} - \theta\,\ic}\ic\,\dd\theta\ +\
\overbrace{2\,\Im\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2} \over 2x}
\,{\dd x \over x}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
\\[1cm] & =
-\pi\ln\pars{\epsilon} + 2\bracks{-\ln\pars{2} - \ln\pars{\epsilon}}\pars{-\,{\pi \over 2}} \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{=}\,\,\,
\bbx{\ds{\pi\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach. By Euler's Beta function, for any $a>0$,
$$ f(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^a} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(a)}\tag{1}$$
hence by considering $\frac{d}{da}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides and evaluating at $a=1$, we get
$$ -\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \psi(1)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\tag{2}$$
directly leading to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \color{red}{\pi\log(2)}$.